# How to send an email alert in WooCommerce whenever an order is placed for more than $500?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a scammer that keeps stealing people's credit cards and then buying things on my WooCommerce website with the stolen credit cards. I have blocked his IP addresses, but he keeps switching IPs (probably with a VPN), so I want to set up an email alert that is sent to me whenever any order is placed that is more than $500 so I can then verify if that is a legitimate order and stop the payment and products from shipping out before its too late.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

---

EDIT

The comment below worked for me, so thank you everyone! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: WooCommerce surely has an action hook that you could use to send out an email when a new order is placed. You could hook into it to check the amount and send an email if it's higher than $500. I'd start there. See: [WooCommerce Hooks: Actions and Filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/).

Comment: Thank you @canterahector. That worked perfect. Appreciate you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever has this same problem, I found a WooCommerce plugin called AutomateWoo at https://woocommerce.com/products/automatewoo/. It costs $99 per year, but it allows you to create a "Workflow" where you can setup a trigger for every time someone completed an order, then you can add a Rule to only fire when the Order Total is greater than $500 and finally you set an action to Send an Email.

[image: AutomateWoo Setup]